# Формирование запроса к БД на основе xml файла

Tags: c#, xml, sql-server, xsd

Задача состоит в следующем - на основе xml и xsd файла необходимо создать БД в ms sql и засунуть туда информацию из xml файла (xml и xsd заранее не известны). Т.к. размер xml заранее не известен, то применять `DataSet.ReadXml` проблематично, вероятна ошибка нехватки памяти.

Самое оптимальное что удалось найти это использование `XmlReader`, но так как чтение идет последовательно сверху вниз, то тут возникает проблема в формировании запроса INSERT - идея в том что если в узле содержаться элементы со значениями и эти элементы одинакового уровня вложенности, то формируем запрос на вставку этих значений в таблицу с именем "родительского" элемента.

```
<a>
   <b>
      <c>val1</c>
      <d>val2</d>
   </b>
   <e>val3</e>
   <f>val4</f>
</a>
```

В данном случае необходимо в таблицу `a` вставить значения `b` `e` `f`, а в таблицу `b` значения `c` и `d`.
Сама база данных сейчас создается на основе `DataSet.ReadXmlSchema` и потом для каждой `DataTable` я создаю таблицу в БД.
Вот что удалось пока написать

```
while (xml.Read())
      {
       if (xml.NodeType.ToString() == "Element")
          {                    
              if (xml.IsEmptyElement != true)
                  {
                     myStack.Push(xml.Name);
                  }
          }
       else if (xml.NodeType.ToString() == "Text")
          {
              string first = myStack.Peek().ToString();
              myStack.Pop();
              string second = myStack.Peek().ToString();
              myStack.Push(first);
              Console.WriteLine("table {0} column {1} value {2}", second, first, xml.Value);
              string cmd = "INSERT INTO " + second + " (" + first + ") VALUES ('" + xml.Value + "')";
              SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(cmd, conn);
              command.ExecuteNonQuery();
         }
     else if (xml.NodeType.ToString() == "EndElement")
         {
             myStack.Pop();
         }
     }
```

Но тут в одну строку только одно значение, что соответственно не правильно.

Update: вот так пытаюсь используя рекурсивную функцию и заполняя массивы из которых затем формировать инструкции

```
static void recursive_read_first (XmlReader xmlr, string e)
        {
            var iterationResult = new List<string>();
            while (xmlr.Read())
            {
                xmlr.MoveToContent();
                if (xmlr.Name != e)
                {
                    if (xmlr.NodeType.ToString() == "Element")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(xmlr.Name);
                        iterationResult.Add(xmlr.Name);
                        recursive_read_first(xmlr.ReadSubtree(), xmlr.Name);

                    }
                    else if (xmlr.NodeType.ToString() == "Text")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(xmlr.Value);
                        iterationResult.Add(xmlr.Value);
                    }
                    else if (xmlr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("EndElement " + xmlr.Name);
                    }
                }
            }
            result.Add(iterationResult);           
        }
```

Comment: Возможно, проще будет сделать с помощью [SQL XML Bulk Load](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms171993.aspx).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov насколько я понял она работает только с одной таблицей, а не с набором таблиц, возможно я ошибаюсь

Comment: Вообще довольно странный запрос - создать БД по XML, при этом у XML структура дерево, у БД структура ориентированный граф. Как в том XML задавать межтабличные связи?

Comment: @Vesper а что вы предлагаете? Невозможно по вашему?

Comment: По крайней мере в схеме нужно задавать, какое значение пихать в тот же `b`, если в нем вложенный XML какого-то вида. Если формат схемы (хотя бы) у вас под контролем, можно в каждой ноде, на которую есть ссылка из другой таблицы планируемой БД (всякие там PK, FK), помечать каким-нибудь id (глобальным в рамках всего XML), и потом на этапе построения БД в парсере хранить id от той записи, которая была создана при добавлении данных из элемента XML в таблицу, и когда будет вноситься инфа с внешней ссылкой, вытащить этот id из хэша/массива и подставить в запрос `INSERT INTO... VALUES(...)`.

Comment: В этом случае для примера XML из запроса вначале в таблицу b будут вставлены (c,d) и получен id записи, после чего в таблицу a будут вставлены значения ((полученный id),e,f).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы не оставлять вопрос без ответа:

```
class Program
{
    class RecordInfo
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Tuple<string, string>> Data { get; set; }
    }

    static Tuple<string, List<RecordInfo>> recursive_read(XmlReader xmlr)
    {
        while (xmlr.NodeType != XmlNodeType.Element && xmlr.Read());

        var text = "";
        string elementName = xmlr.Name;

        var childrenData = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
        var result = new List<RecordInfo>();

        while (xmlr.Read())
        {
            if (xmlr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
            {
                var childName = xmlr.Name;

                var subtree = xmlr.ReadSubtree();
                subtree.Read(); // проматываем текущий элемент

                var subtreeResult = recursive_read(subtree);

                childrenData.Add(Tuple.Create(childName, subtreeResult.Item1));

                result.AddRange(subtreeResult.Item2);
            }
            else if (xmlr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text)
            {
                text = xmlr.Value;
            }
        }

        if (childrenData.Any())
        {
            result.Add(new RecordInfo
            {
                Name = elementName,
                Data = childrenData
            });
        }

        return Tuple.Create(text, result);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var reader = XmlReader.Create(@"c:\temp\1.xml");
        var records = recursive_read(reader);
        foreach (RecordInfo record in records.Item2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("INSERT INTO {0} ({1}) VALUES ({2})",
                record.Name,
                String.Join(",", record.Data.Select(d => d.Item1)),
                // стоит использовать параметры, а не клеить SQL напрямую
                String.Join(",", record.Data.Select(d => "'" + d.Item2 + "'")) 
                );
        }
    }
}
```

выводит:

```
INSERT INTO b (c,d) VALUES ('val1','val2')
INSERT INTO a (b,e,f) VALUES ('','val3','val4')
```

Если объем достаточно большой, то лучше забрасывать результат в `ConcurrentQueue` вместо строк

```
result.Add(new RecordInfo
{
    Name = elementName,
    Data = childrenData
});
```

и в отдельном потоке выполнять SQL по мере поступления.

Comment: спасибо, но никак не могу понять конструкцию `while (xmlr.NodeType != XmlNodeType.Element && xmlr.Read());` Почему там нет тела цикла `{}`

Comment: @e1s смысл - вызывать `Read` пока `NodeType` не станет равным Element.  это по сути  `while (xmlr.NodeType != XmlNodeType.Element) { xmlr.Read(); }`, но с проверкой что `Read` вернул. т.е. аналог - ` `while (xmlr.NodeType != XmlNodeType.Element) { if (!xmlr.Read()) { break; } }`

Comment: те вот так `while (xmlr.NodeType != XmlNodeType.Element && xmlr.Read()) { } ` правильно я вас понял? Что то типо заглушки?

Comment: @e1s да, просто заглушка

Comment: А как лучше поступить с id ?

Comment: @e1s с каким id?

Comment: Для взаимосвязи между таблицами, у дочерней таблицы, допустим поле вида `имяродительскойтаблицы_Id`

Comment: @e1s можно линковать RecordInfo друг с другом в recursive_read - и отслеживать id при вставке

Comment: если честно я Вас не понял

Comment: @e1s тогда попробуйте найти решение самостоятельно ) Пишите тесты, начиная с тривиальных случаев, и заставляйте их проходить.. Код для корректной вставки в пачку таблиц, с отслеживанием зависимостей и порядка - это пара сотен строк. Вместить это в ответ, при этом не зная ни схему базы, ни особенности вашего приложения, ни вообще что у вас там происходит - нереально.

Comment: @e1s Хотя если честно, я бы на вашем месте ограничился компиляцией в x64, снятием галки Prefer 32 Bit, выставлением `<gcAllowVeryLargeObjects>` и докупкой пары планок памяти. Проще, надежнее и дешевле )

Comment: Нет я про механизм этой линковки, что вы под этим подразумеваете?

Comment: @e1s добавьте в RecordInfo поле типа RecordInfo - чтобы RecordInfo для `b` ссылалась на RecordInfo для `a`. или наоборот - как у вас там в базе свзязи стоят. При генерации  SQL обрабатывайте RecordInfo в нужном порядке - в том, в котором зависимости в базе нужно проставлять. Там же выбирайте id и проставляйте их у зависимых записей (id можно тоже прямо в RecordInfo положить, и заполнять в момент вставки RecordInfo в базу). Как-то так.

Comment: `Class RecordInfo {RecordInfo link ....}` или лучше при генерации запросов Insert это делать? Добавлять поле Id